# Grails, google visualization plugin

Tags: grails, google-visualization, grails-orm, grails-2.0

I am very new to grails and I'm trying to develop a simple application.

Can someone please give me a step by step guidance on how I can create a google visualization chart in Grails, given that I have two domain classes.

```
User
Transaction
```

The relationship is

```
User { static hasMany = [transactions:Transactions] }
Transaction { static belongsTo = User }
```

In other words, what libraries do I include, what .js files do I have to create, how to configure the UrlMapping.groovy etc, what extra controllers/domain-classes??

I tried so many times, read documentations, watched tutorials, but all I get is errors.

PS: Assume some random fields in both classes for the sake of the example.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As this site's purpose is to guide and help learning, nobody is going to give You all the code so you can just copy it.
As an advice - If you are very new to Grails, **start with simple things step by step**. I don't know how far you have gone with your domain classes, but do the following:

**GRAILS PART**
 - Fully create both of Your domain classes
 - Either directly through the database, in [Bootstrap](http://grails.asia/grails-tutorial-for-beginners-display-data-from-the-database/) or using CRUD (it can be generated with a command in grails) fill it with some data
 - In controller create an action where you take all the data and send to gsp page
 - In .gsp page just take all that list of your Domain objects (i.e. Users) and just print them out.
**HTML part**
 - Read briefly about one of Google visualization chart types (the one you want to use) - how to create, what data is needed etc.
 - Needed JS is explained [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_load_libs#basic-library-loading)
 - Download an example
 - Run the example in the browser, edit the properties and simply play with it until you understand what is what.
**TOGETHER PART**
 - Read about how to pass data to .gsp in JSON format [here](https://grails.org/wiki/Converters%20Reference)
 - Then implement that example in your Grails project, passing the data in JSON format to the chart.
*Good luck learning!*

Comment: my biggest problem here is where do i place the gsp, file, and what they actually are.

Comment: @DonCode well, then it's too hard and inappropriate to explain all the grails in stackoverflow answer. GSP files are Views as from MVC principle. Maybe [check this](http://grails.asia/grails-tutorial-for-beginners/) tutorial for explaining the basics of file patterns and a lot more. And i'd really appreciate if you accepted my answer as it properly explains your problem. Good luck